# How to load image asynchronously using UIImageView+AFNetworking in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, afnetworking

I am using this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://oldmaker.com/glamberry_v2/ios_Loading-Spinners.gif"]]];
```

but this is taking too much time. I want to use `AFNetworking` to make loading speed faster.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have found 'SDWebImage` to be the best. It has disk caching too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

It supports asynchronous downloading as well as caching.

Usage

Just  #import the `UIImageView+WebCache.h` header

```
  [imgView sd_setImageWithURL:Url_Of_The_Image placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sampleimage.png"]];
```

Comment: is it possible to add url image for both placeholder image and mail image?

Comment: i hope not, as it will deteriorate the functionality of the framework. It will be a bad idea to use url for placeholder image.

Answer (score 4):

```
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"  

//...
[self.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"image_url"]];
```

Comment: in viewDidload : UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"artistCell" bundle:nil];
    [_tblArtist registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
           forCellReuseIdentifier:@"artistC"];
    [_tblArtist registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"artistC"];       and in cellForRowAtIndex:static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"artistC";

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];                                                                                i am using this but while scrolling down and up Image changes in some cells.

Answer (score 3):

you can load async image like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        });
    });
```

i you need set this image into imageview so try use this:

```
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:FRAME];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            img.image = image;
            img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

No answer seems to handle this completely, so, to have more info...

First of all, you should include the AFNetworking category for `UIImageView`:

```
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"
```

If you're using CocoaPods, this line should be:

```
#import <AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h>
```

After that, you should have at least one `UIImageView` (I'm going to assume you have an `IBOutlet` connected):

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImageView;
```

Then you can load your image in code:

```
// Define a placeholder image that will be shown while the remote image
// loads. If you don't want a placeholder image, just set it to nil.
// Note that this placeholder image is local (it should be in your
// asset files/collection).
UIImage *myPlaceholderImage = nil; // Or use [UIImage imageNamed:@"..."];

// First, cancel other tasks that could be downloading images.
// If you only do this once, this is probably not needed, but it's not harmful to
// always have it before loading an image with setImageWithURL: and derivatives.
[self.myImageView cancelImageDownloadTask];

// Set up a NSURL for the image you want.
// I'm gonna use this wonderful owl: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/10-dithering-opt.jpg
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/10-dithering-opt.jpg"];

// Check if the URL is valid
if ( imageURL ) {
    // The URL is valid so we'll use it to load the image asynchronously.
    // Pass the placeholder image that will be shown while the
    // remote image loads.
    [self.myImageView setImageWithURL:imageURL
                     placeholderImage:myPlaceholderImage];
}
else {
    // The imageURL is invalid, just show the placeholder image.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.myImageView.image = myPlaceholderImage;
    });
}
```

If, for any reason, you need to do **something** to the remote image before delivering it to the `UIImageView`, you can use the `setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:` method. I'm going to transform the received `UIImage` to another `UIImage` in template mode, so it will be colored with the `tintColor` of the `UIImageView` (of course, this image of an owl will not look good, this should be a plain icon with transparency):

```
UIImage *placeholderImage = nil;

NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/10-dithering-opt.jpg"];

if ( imageURL ) {
    // Check NSURLRequestCachePolicy enumeration for other values.
    // 60 seconds in timeoutInterval is the default for iOS.
    NSURLRequest *imageRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL 
                                                  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                              timeoutInterval:60.0f];

    [self.myImageView cancelImageDownloadTask];

    // We'll keep a weak reference to our UIImageView so it won't have
    // any possibility of being retained by our success/failure blocks.
    __weak typeof(self.myImageView) weakImageView = self.myImageView;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.myImageView setImageWithURLRequest:imageRequest
                                placeholderImage:placeholderImage
                                         success:^(NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, UIImage * _Nonnull image) {
                                                   UIImage *tintedImage = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
                                                   weakImageView.image  = tintedImage;
                                               }
                                               failure:^(NSURLRequest * _Nonnull request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
                                                   weakImageView.image = placeholderImage;
                                               }];
    });

}
else {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.myImageView.image = placeholderImage;
    });
}
```

And yes, I know this is an old question, but this should serve as reference.

Answer (score 0):

[Haneke](https://github.com/Haneke/Haneke) will also do the job.

```
[imageView hnk_setImageFromURL:url];
```

And if you want to load with `AFNetworking`:

```
[self.someImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"urlOfImage"]];
```